# Use Object.assign in a loop

Tags: angular, typescript

Considder a very simplified example.

Lets say we have an object of a class (obj in this case) that contains an arbitrary amount of other objects. Essentially the objects contained by obj are also classes, that have their own instance variables and functions.

```
obj = {
    item1 : {id: '', data: ''},
    item2 : {id: '', someField:'', anotherField:''}
}
```

This is an example of the parent object class definition (I know the synrtax is not completely correct, but this is just for example purposes)

```
import { item1 } from "./item1.model";
import { item2 } from "./item2.model";

export class Obj{
    public item1: item1
    public item2: item2

    constructor(item1: item1 =new item1(), item2: item2 =new item2()){
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
    }

    set(data){
        Object.assign(this.item1, data.item1);
        Object.assign(this.item2, data.item2)
    }
}
```

And this is an example of one of the child classes

```
export class item1{
    public someField: string;
    public abotherField: string;

    constructor(someField: string ='?',abotherField: string ='?'){
        this.someField = someField;
        this.abotherField = abotherField;
    }

    set(data){
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }

    someFunction(){
        
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve now, is have a function that receives some data as an argument and updates the instance variables in the classes. This data needs to be assigned to the respective child object if that makes sense?

This is working so far

```
set(data){
        Object.assign(this.item1, data.item1);
        Object.assign(this.item2, data.item2)
    }
```

I would like to have something that is more generic, like a forEach that loops over each key and assigns the data correctly.

I am using the assign approach because it is the only way I have found so far that requires less code and does not overwrite or discard the methods in each child object.

I am trying to go for something like this

```
set(data){
        Object.keys(this).forEach(key=>{
            Object.assign(this[key], data[key])
        });
    }
```

Is this the correct approach to follow, or are there better ways to achieve this?
I should also mention, this is for an Angular project

Answer (score 0):

Since in some cases you may not get **data** for every field in  **Obj**, In such case where **item2** is in data but not in **Obj** you will get an error. You may change your loop as follows.

```
set(data){
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key=>{
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            Object.assign(this[key], data[key])
         }
    });
}
```

[Sample Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pghc7k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodels.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)